# renaming of Strunk & White badge

Tags: discussion, badges

As *Strunk & White* is criticized by linguists (because they regard it as [prescriptivist and outdated and occasionally incorrect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style#Criticism)), would it be possible to rename this badge? To me, this badge feels a bit like a prize awarded that carries the name of (say) a famous politician that has fallen into disrepute ;-)

What about "Assistant Editor"?

Comment: That would apply across the SE network: you'd need to ask on the main meta site.

Comment: Done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135960/renaming-of-strunk-white-badge

Comment: @user14996: Please don't double post things across SO/SE sites. Questions can be migrated to another site by a moderator. I will close this now here so that the same question isn't around twice.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thank you for the information on policy. I thought double-posting (and then linking, like I've done) was what was expected of me. How can one ask a moderator to migrate a question? Would it be possible to rename "closed as off-topic" by "closed due to duplicate on main/other meta/site"? If that's not possible, that might be another candidate for a main meta ...

Comment: You can use the 'flag' link below any post to notify moderators. And no, I can't rename it. I can only migrate it, but it's already there so I see no reason to create a duplicate. Feel free to simply delete this question here.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Okay, in this particular case I'll keep the question, because this comment thread is useful (for a newbie like me). If you'd say that this information is clearly and accessibly available elsewhere, I'll be happy to delete everything, though.

Comment: @Martin: there should be no reason why someone can't bring up a topic that pertains to all sites on an individual site. I don't know that this is particularly useful or interesting to Tex.SE users, but in the future please either let the discussion fall out locally (as it may) or close because it *isn't* relevant here (if it isn't) - plenty of things that nominally apply network-wide aren't actually all that important outside of individual sites, so establishing consensus locally can help to understand the need (or lack thereof).